# MarkerView is cutting off the value on the right side of the graph

Tags: java, android, linechart

Using the Markerview to show the value on the graph when it is touched. But when it is touched on the right side of the graph it goes beyond the screen. And when it is touched on the left side it does not go beyond but its arrow does not point to correct value on the graph. I am using mpchart Android library.

This is my custom Markerview class xymarkerview.java

```
public class XYMarkerView extends MarkerView {

private TextView tvContent;
private IAxisValueFormatter xAxisValueFormatter;

private DecimalFormat format;

public XYMarkerView(Context context, IAxisValueFormatter xAxisValueFormatter) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.custom_marker_view);

    this.xAxisValueFormatter = xAxisValueFormatter;
    tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    format = new DecimalFormat("###.0");
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {


    tvContent.setText(format.format(e.getY()));

    super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
}


@Override
public MPPointF getOffset() {
    return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
}



}
```

This is my customXYmarker.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rectangle"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text=""
    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_arrow"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1.5dp"
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_arrow_down"
    />
```

**Left Side Marker problem:** 
[image]

**Right Side Marker problem** 
[image]

It is working perfectly on the center values but not working properly on the values in the far left side or far right side.

Comment: did u find any solution @NIMESH SACHIN